Is there a workaround to avoid using heavy for loop to calculate each item's loss in the batch for my code?
I am currently working with a gaussian splatting codebase that projects points and performs rasterization for one single image. Because of this, since I am doing this for multiple images (batched), I end up having to use a heavy for-loop to go through each item in the batch, project and rasterize them to get a render and then compare each of it to the corresponding ground truth. Is there a better way of going about this? Ideally, this should be parallelizable since each image is independent. Will I have to edit the project and rasterize functions themselves, all the way back to their custom CUDA kernel implementations?
for original_images, tensors in train_loader_tqdm:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for i in range(images.size(0)): 
        xys, depths, radii, conics, num_tiles_hit = project_gaussians_2d(means2d[i], L_elems[i], H, W,tile_bounds)  
  
        out_img = rasterize_gaussians_sum(xys, depths, radii, conics, num_tiles_hit, rgbs[i], opacity, H, W, BLOCK_H, BLOCK_W, background=background, return_alpha=False)

        rendered_img = out_img
        image = original_images[i].permute((1,2,0)) 
        loss = criterion(rendered_img, image, mask, model.loss_type, loss_lambda) 
        batch_loss += loss
  
    batch_loss /= images.size(0) 
    batch_loss.backward()  
    optimizer.step()

means2d, L_elems and rgbs are all batched that are derived earlier from passing the images through a different neural network model.
